# CRS vs SRS in zk-SNARK

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

Are Common Reference String (CRS) and Structured Reference String (SRS) is the same in preprocessing phase of zk-SNARK? Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been variants of definition in the literature, but I would say the zkproof.org's effort to standardize these terminology is a good reference. See [page 82 here](https://docs.zkproof.org/pages/reference/reference.pdf)

[image]

I recall there's some discussions on Twitter between Benedikt Bunz, Vanishree Rao and others [here](https://twitter.com/benediktbuenz/status/1297974016041340928)